# React Router Redirect drops param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I am using the `next` version of React Router, and it seems to be dropping params. I expect the redirect below to retain the value of `channelId`, but the `to` route uses the literal string "`:channelId`" in the path instead.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
  <Route path="/channels/:channelId/modes/:modeId" component={Window} />
  <Redirect
    from="/channels/:channelId"
    to="/channels/:channelId/modes/window" />
</Switch>
```

This looks like a [resolved issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1034#issuecomment-113526156), but it's not working. Is there something else I need to pass to the `to` route?

Comment: Did you find the solution, Matt?

Comment: @SebastianRoth I never did, unfortunately. I'm doing things a different way now, using redirect within the component itself. However, it would be great to get this verified because it should work as advertised in the thread linked above.

Comment: FWIW, I've asked this question in the react-router Discord channel. I ended up doing something similar, with a route that has a render method that returns a Redirect with values pulled from props.

Comment: I don't think the link you provided is to the same issue. That OP is looking to add extra params in addition to the ones :defined in from/to. I'm having the same situation where :someId is coming in as 1234, but getting redirected to a literal ":someID" string in the URL. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 26):

Here's what I've been using, similar to the other answer but without a dependency:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/:id"
  render={props => (
    <Redirect to={`foo/${props.match.params.id}/bar`} />;
  )}
/>
```

Comment: this definitely works in `react-router-dom@4.2.2`. weird that the `Redirect` has to be forced to do this this way

Comment: I get `/foo/undefined/bar` in version `  react-router-dom": "^4.2.2`

Comment: This works perfectly. Note that you need to add a slash before `/foo` so it will be an absolute path.

Answer (score 12):

I found no such logic in React Router 4 sources, so write own workaround:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class RedirectWithParams extends Component {
  render() {
    const { exact, from } = this.props;    
    return (
      <Route
        exact={exact}
        path={from}
        component={this.getRedirectComponent}
      />);
  }

  getRedirectComponent = ({ match: { params } }) => {
    const { push, to } = this.props;
    const pathTo = pathToRegexp.compile(to);
    return <Redirect to={pathTo(params)} push={push} />
  }
};

RedirectWithParams.propTypes = {
  exact: PropTypes.bool,
  from: PropTypes.string,
  to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  push: PropTypes.bool
};

export default RedirectWithParams;
```

usage example:

```
<Switch>
   <RedirectWithParams
      exact from={'/resuorce/:id/section'}
      to={'/otherResuorce/:id/section'}
   />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Looks almost the same as your code: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/generatePath.js

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
  <Route path="/channels/:channelId/modes/:modeId" component={Window} />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/channels/:channelId"
    render={({ match }) => (
      <Redirect to={`/channels/${match.params.channelId}/modes/window`} />   
    )}
  />
</Switch>
```

Comment: this answer should be marked correct. works nicely with less code

Answer (score 5):

I did this, and it worked:

```js
<switch>
  <Route path={`/anypath/:id`} component={Anycomponent} />
   <Route
      exact
      path="/requestedpath/:id"
      render={({ match }) => {
        if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {
          return <Redirect to={`/signin`} />;
        } else {
          return <Redirect to={`/anypath/${match.params.id}`} />;
        }
      }}
    />
</switch>
```

Answer (score 4):

This functionality has been added to React Router 4 [as of 4.3.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v4.3.0). If you're locked into a version before 4.3.x, Gleb's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Using React Router 4.3.1 , I needed to put my `Redirect` tag inside a `Switch` tag for it to work

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [`generatePath`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath):

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, generatePath } from "react-router";

<Switch>
  <Route component={PageOne} path="/one" />
  <Route component={PageTwo} path="/two/:id" />
  <Route
    path="/three/:id"
    render={props => (
      <Redirect
        to={generatePath("/two/:id", {
          id: props.match.params.id,
        })}
      />
    )}
  />
  <Route component={NotFoundPage} path="*" />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

In React Router v6+ you could create your own `NavigateWithParams` like so

```
import { Navigate, NavigateProps, generatePath, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

interface Props extends NavigateProps {
  to: string;
}

const NavigateWithParams: React.FC<Props> = ({ to, ...props }) => {
  const params = useParams();

  return <Navigate {...props} to={generatePath(to, params)} />;
};

export default NavigateWithParams;
```

and use it like so:

```
  <Route path="/old/:param" element={<NavigateWithParams to="/new/:param" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Short general version using `generatePath` that worked for me (redirecting from `from` path to `to` path, both having the same parameters):

```
import { Route, Redirect, generatePath } from "react-router"

<Route path={from} 
       exact
       component={({match}) => 
             <Redirect to={generatePath(to, match.params)} />} />
```